# How can I get from Historic Centre of Cartagena to La Boquilla by bus?

Tags: buses, colombia, cartagena

How can I get from the Historic Centre of Cartagena (the Colombian one) to La Boquilla by public bus?

I can see there are a number of different busses on the streets, but I'm unclear on which bus I need to catch.  I haven't been able to find any route information by searching the Internet.

Comment: Never been there (yet), but looking at the map, I'm thinking I would just walk.  Rome2Rio suggests Uber.  http://cartagenainfo.net/buses/eng_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VehiTrans has a buseta route](http://vehitrans.com/rutas.html) which runs from Centro Historico to La Boquilla. Look for the VehiTrans bus and check the sign in the window, which for the correct route will list Boquilla as the final stop. If you can't see the sign for some reason, you can also ask the bus driver.